# Sorting in SQL w/ multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sorting

I'm new to SQL, how would I go along with sorting the following:

I have three different type of dev projects(type 1,2, and 3). Type 1 and 2 also have an analysis that is linked with them. The analysis and dev type 1 and 2 will have a linking parent id, how would I sort with these specs:

Process Items in the following sequence

- Dev type 3 projects
- Dev type 1 or 2 projects combined with their analysis item (dev item columns take precedence analysis item columns)
- Remaining analysis projects with no related dev projects

****EDIT**** the lower ParentID should come first after these three specs

Example columns of the table are:

```
|ParentID| AnalysisItemID | DevItemId | DevType |
    1          Null             2          1
    4           5              Null       Null 
    6           8              Null       Null      
    8          Null             9          3  
    6          Null             7          2
    1           3              Null       Null
```

Sorted Output would be:

```
|ParentID| AnalysisItemID | DevItemId | DevType |
    8          Null             9          3   
    1          Null             2          1
    1           3              Null       Null
    6          Null             7          2 
    6           8              Null       Null 
    4           5              Null       Null
```

Comment: have you tried anything?  which order by clause gets you closest?

Comment: I've yet to try anything, was going to try peoples suggestions and go from there

Comment: what is your logic to sort? If you give us ur logic then we can provide a better solution.

Comment: My logic is how I stated in the question; type 3's then type 1 and 2's w/ their analysis preceding them, and then any remaining analysis on its own. I did forget to mention the lower parent id will go first. is that clear enough? thank you so much

Comment: Final answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16bdf/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you want to sort the data by the parent id, with the ordering based on the maximum devtype for the parent.

For this, you need to join to a summary table to get the information for the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select parentId, max(devtype) as maxdt
      from t
      group by parentId
     ) p
     on t.parentId = p.parentId
order by (case when maxdt = 3 then 1
               when maxdt in (1, 2) then 2
               else 3
          end), parentId, devtype desc
```

Comment: If I wanted to put this at the end of a stored procedure to sort the table, how would I change it?

Comment: @user2433152 . . . I don't understand the question.  You can put this anywhere in a stored procedure, including at the end.

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not sort my table t. It remained the same

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but you can order by the result of a `CASE` in SQL. I imagine something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN DevType = 3 THEN 1
                 WHEN DevType IN (1, 2) THEN AnalysisItemID + 1
                 ELSE [bignumber] + AnalysisItemID END
```

could do what you require.

Obviously, that `case` can also be encapsulated into a user-defined function for readability if required. There's a chance that that could affect performance, however.